# Have you heard that (something) is hematopoietic?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

There is a technical term "hematopoietic" which implies something can cause the production of all types of blood cells in the bone marrow. Although, I am sure that an MD would recognize the intention in this sentence, I have no idea how shall one indicate such a thing in English in a manner that ordinary people would understand it. I was wondering if you could help me find a natural and idiomatic way to indicate this message to native listeners so that they could comprehend the matter in the question:

> - Have you heard that (wine, red meat, pistachio etc.) is hematopoietic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach I'd personally use is exactly what you've done in your opening sentence!

> Have you heard that (wine, red meat, pistachio etc.) **can promote the production of *[all types of]* blood cells in the bone marrow**?

I've used box brackets around "all types of" because you could optionally omit that part - since your target audience might not know of - or be concerned with - the different types of cells in blood.

Yes, by rewriting the sentence in such a manner it definitely becomes longer, but that is almost inevitable when trying to frame a sentence for a wider audience.

The word **hematopoietic** is jargon in its purest sense: "special words or expressions used by a profession or group that are difficult for others to understand". The reason jargon evolved is to allow a group to speak in "shorthand" so as to communicate faster (through brevity) while maintaining accuracy at the same time.

When we remove jargon, the reverse happens - sentences become longer and more verbose.

Comment: Very informative, comprehensive and helpful response @Phylyp. Thank you very much for the help. It is really appreciated.